# Impossible to modify struct inside array?

Tags: go

I'm just starting to learn golang and I have the following code:

https://play.golang.org/p/OBsf9MRLD8

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type ResourceUsage struct {
    Type string
}
type Node struct {
    Resources []ResourceUsage
}

func main(){
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    nodes := make([]Node, 2)
    nodes[0] = Node{}
    nodes[1] = Node{}

    for _,n := range nodes {
        n.Resources = append(n.Resources, ResourceUsage{Type: "test"})
    }
    encoder.Encode(nodes)
}
```

I was hoping it to print

```
[{"Resources":[{"Type:"test"}]},{"Resources":[{"Type:"test"}]}]
```

But instead I get:

```
[{"Resources":null},{"Resources":null}]
```

How can I accomplish the expected output?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Structs are copied in range loops. You need to access by index.

```
for i := range nodes {
    nodes[i].Resources = append(nodes[i].Resources, ResourceUsage{Type: "test"})
}
```

You could also choose to use pointers, which would not copy data.

```
nodes := make([]*Node, 2)
nodes[0] = &Node{}
nodes[1] = &Node{}
```

[@Kaedys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551301/kaedys) points out, you can't take the address of the iterated value.

```
for _, v := range nodes {
    &v // mistake
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Worth noting, this also applies if you ever try to take the address of objects using a for loop.  You must use an index loop, because the `for _, n := range o` form copies the object at each index into a single address location. https://play.golang.org/p/jkB85jgVKw